# Have Swing GUI elements, without large spaces

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

My issue is, rather than the elements being on top of each other neatly, there are huge blocks of space unnecessarily in between each element of the gui that I use in the program.

I'm trying to have it like this:

```
label
textfield, button
textarea
```

But instead it's coming out like

```
label
(blotch of space)
textfield, button
(blotch of space)
textarea
```

when I run it. Any help is appreciated, I've really been trying to figure it out by myself.
    package guiprojj;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.json.parsers.JSONParser;
import com.json.parsers.JsonParserFactory;


public class gui {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame maingui = new JFrame("Gui");
        JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
        final JTextArea movieinfo = new JTextArea(5,20);
        final JTextField movietext = new JTextField(16);
        final JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(movieinfo);
        final JLabel titlee = new JLabel("Enter movie name here:");
        JPanel pangui = new JPanel();
        JPanel pangui2 = new JPanel();
        maingui.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
        maingui.add(titlee);
        pangui.add(movietext);
        pangui.add(enter);
        pangui2.add(scrolll);
        //scrolll.add(movieinfo);
        //pangui.add(movieinfo);
        maingui.setResizable(false);
        maingui.setVisible(true);
        movieinfo.setLineWrap(true);
        movieinfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        movieinfo.setEditable(false);
        maingui.add(pangui);
        maingui.add(pangui2);

        scrolll.getPreferredSize();
        //pangui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        //pangui.add(scrolll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //movieinfo.add(scrolll);
        maingui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        maingui.pack();
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
            {
                System.out.println(Test.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));
                 JsonParserFactory factory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
                 JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
                 Map jsonData=parser.parseJson(Test.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));
                 String Title = (String)jsonData.get("Title");
                 String Year = (String)jsonData.get("Year");
                 String Plot = (String)jsonData.get("Plot");
                 movieinfo.setText("Title: "+Title+"\nYear: "+ Year +"\nPlot: "+Plot);
            }
            });

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a layout manager that works the way you expect it to. There are several managers included with Java and I recommend you start here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

This will give you a good visual introduction to the various layout managers and should give you the foundation you need to pick the right one.

Answer (score 3):

This is how GridLayout works: all grid cells are the same size, probably the largest preferredSize of its components. Better to do what I suggested in my last answer: nesting BorderLayout using JPanels.

Answer (score 0):

if u need to put them separately or with variable space , just use GridBag Layout or use absolute layout i.e. no layout, with manual positioning

it would be easy using for loop for aligning in absolute layout (using setBounds(x,y,width,height)